# Ajax request only works the 2nd time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have created a wp login form via ajax, but the problem is that it only works the 2nd time around i.e. a user fills out password and username, clicks submit, does not work, if they click submit again, it does. Any suggestions?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  // Perform AJAX login/register on form submit
  $('body').on('submit', 'form#login2', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
    $('form#login2 p.status').show().text(ajax_auth_object.loadingmessage);
    action = 'ajaxlogin';
    username = $('form#login2 #username').val();
    password = $('form#login2 #password').val();
    email = '';
    security = $('form#login2 #security').val();
    ctrl = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: ajax_auth_object.ajaxurl,
      data: {
        'action': action,
        'username': username,
        'password': password,
        'email': email,
        'security': security
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status) {
        $('form#login2 p.status').show().text('please try again');
      },

      success: function(jqXHR, status) {
        document.location.href = ajax_auth_object.redirecturl;
      }

    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Comment: Did you see what's happening in the console?

Comment: yeah, getting message, saying login is empty

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that you are calling `e.preventDefault()` too late. It should be the first line of your handler:

```
  $('body').on('submit', 'form#login2', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!$(this).valid()) return false;
    // Other code omitted

   });
```

Also, as an aside, the `preventDefault()` method is no longer recommended for cases in which you only have one listener. You should use `stopPropagation()` instead.

Comment: thanks for the info, i tried moving it up, but still same problem exists

Comment: @DEM Okay, so if you are using any modern browser you can hit the F12 key to bring up dev tools, where you can insert breakpoints and watch what's happening in your javascript code as it executes. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: im using dev tools, but mostly just the console to torubleshoot

Comment: Put breakpoints in your code and/or add watches to your variables so that you can more quickly grasp what is happening in your code. Console logging is good, but debugging is better.

Comment: thanks for the tip, where would u recommend i add the breakpoints?

Comment: Well, I don't know your code as well as you do, so coming from that perspective I would just put a breakpoint on the first line of the handler and then step through it (F11 key if you're using Chrome).